# Using XPath to get the first element and pass in the value

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Using `XPath` to select the first dropdown and pass in the value, then find the second dropdown and pass in the value. This is what I have so far.

```
class pageCommon(Page):

    def __init__(self, driver, fieldName):

        self.driver = driver
        try:
            self.text = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tr/th//*[text()="%s"]' % fieldName)
        except:
            self.text = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tr/th//*[text()="%s"]' % (fieldName + ":"))


    # take action - to edit any page[enterValue variable has to be a list]
    def take_action(self, enterValue):
        # ensures the edit mode is on
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_id("edit").click()
        except:
            pass

        # currently the it is hardcoded. 
        self.text.find_element_by_xpath('./..//..//./td/select)[2]')
        Select(self.text.find_element_by_xpath('./..//..//./td/select)[2]')).select_by_visible_text(enterValue)
```

if I use this method it does not work. probably the `XPath` is not right but when I hard code the full `xpath` without initiating it it works. This is the `XPath` I am using which makes it work.

```
//tr/th//*[text()="Currency:"]/..//..//./td/select)[2]
```

Also, since the `enterValue` parameter is a list. If a user passes, let's say `["ENG", "AUS"]`, then it should select `ENG` for the first dropdown and for the second dropdown it should select `AUS`. Not sure how to approach this.

I am struggling with two things here:

1. getting the correct `XPath`
2. adding a loop so I do not have the hardcode the select order number

Here this is what it looks like

[image]

and this is what drop downs look like:

[image]

Here is the HTML code for the first dropdown:

```
<tr>
  <th valign="top"  class="Form">
    <label for="currencyid">Currency:</label>
  </th>
    <td  id="sf_60_td" class="Form">
      <table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px">1</td>
          <td>
            <select name="currencyid" id="currencyid" onchange="updateForEx(this.form)" class="XSmall">
              <option value=USD selected >USD</option>
              <option value=CAD>CAD</option>
              <option value=FRCA>FRCA</option>
              <option value=MXN>MXN</option>
              <option value=EUR>EUR</option>
              <option value=GBP>GBP</option>
              <option value=HKD>HKD</option>
              <option value=JPY>JPY</option>
              <option value=INR>INR</option>
              <option value=CLP>CLP</option>
              <option value=PEN>PEN</option>
              <option value=ZAR>ZAR</option>
              <option value=CNY>CNY</option>
              <option value=NAD>NAD</option>
              <option value=TRY>TRY</option>
              <option value=AUD>AUD</option>
              <option value=BRL>BRL</option>
              <option value=COP>COP</option>
              <option value=CYP>CYP</option>
              <option value=CZK>CZK</option>
              <option value=DKK>DKK</option>
              <option value=EGP>EGP</option>
              <option value=ETB>ETB</option>
              <option value=FJD>FJD</option>
              <option value=GHC>GHC</option>
              <option value=HUF>HUF</option>
              <option value=IDR>IDR</option>
              <option value=ILS>ILS</option>
              <option value=JOD>JOD</option>
              <option value=KZT>KZT</option>
              <option value=KES>KES</option>
              <option value=KWD>KWD</option>
              <option value=LBP>LBP</option>
              <option value=MYR>MYR</option>
              <option value=MAD>MAD</option>
              <option value=NZD>NZD</option>
              <option value=TWD>TWD</option>
              <option value=NOK>NOK</option>
              <option value=OMR>OMR</option>
              <option value=PKR>PKR</option>
              <option value=PHP>PHP</option>
              <option value=PLN>PLN</option>
              <option value=QAR>QAR</option>
              <option value=RUB>RUB</option>
              <option value=SAR>SAR</option>
              <option value=SGD>SGD</option>
              <option value=SKK>SKK</option>
              <option value=KRW>KRW</option>
              <option value=SEK>SEK</option>
              <option value=CHF>CHF</option>
              <option value=THB>THB</option>
              <option value=TTD>TTD</option>
              <option value=TND>TND</option>
              <option value=UAH>UAH</option>
              <option value=AED>AED</option>
              <option value=VND>VND</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px">=</td>
          <td style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px">
            <input type="text" class="textreadonly" name="exrate" id="exrate" value="1.0" style="text-align:right;width:60px"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select name="excur" id="excur" onchange="updateForEx(this.form)" >
              <option value=USD>USD</option>
              <option value=CAD selected >CAD</option>
              <option value=FRCA>FRCA</option>
              <option value=MXN>MXN</option>
              <option value=EUR>EUR</option>
              <option value=GBP>GBP</option>
              <option value=HKD>HKD</option>
              <option value=JPY>JPY</option>
              <option value=INR>INR</option>
              <option value=CLP>CLP</option>
              <option value=PEN>PEN</option>
              <option value=ZAR>ZAR</option>
              <option value=CNY>CNY</option>
              <option value=NAD>NAD</option>
              <option value=TRY>TRY</option>
              <option value=AUD>AUD</option>
              <option value=BRL>BRL</option>
              <option value=COP>COP</option>
              <option value=CYP>CYP</option>
              <option value=CZK>CZK</option>
              <option value=DKK>DKK</option>
              <option value=EGP>EGP</option>
              <option value=ETB>ETB</option>
              <option value=FJD>FJD</option>
              <option value=GHC>GHC</option>
              <option value=HUF>HUF</option>
              <option value=IDR>IDR</option>
              <option value=ILS>ILS</option>
              <option value=JOD>JOD</option>
              <option value=KZT>KZT</option>
              <option value=KES>KES</option>
              <option value=KWD>KWD</option>
              <option value=LBP>LBP</option>
              <option value=MYR>MYR</option>
              <option value=MAD>MAD</option>
              <option value=NZD>NZD</option>
              <option value=TWD>TWD</option>
              <option value=NOK>NOK</option>
              <option value=OMR>OMR</option>
              <option value=PKR>PKR</option>
              <option value=PHP>PHP</option>
              <option value=PLN>PLN</option>
              <option value=QAR>QAR</option>
              <option value=RUB>RUB</option>
              <option value=SAR>SAR</option>
              <option value=SGD>SGD</option>
              <option value=SKK>SKK</option>
              <option value=KRW>KRW</option>
              <option value=SEK>SEK</option>
              <option value=CHF>CHF</option>
              <option value=THB>THB</option>
              <option value=TTD>TTD</option>
              <option value=TND>TND</option>
              <option value=UAH>UAH</option>
              <option value=AED>AED</option>
              <option value=VND>VND</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px">
            <input type=hidden name="examt" id="examt" value="0.0"/>2016-12-20 11:30</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Can you provide the relevant html? Hard to comment on whether they're correct or not without seeing it!

Comment: @Josh, I just edited my code and added the HTML code

Comment: Thanks, are you not able to find these elements by their id instead?

Comment: No i cant use the id. I have to use the input type. The purpose of my function is to find the field then find its type then enter the value according to that. I haven't added the full code here but I just wanted to give you an idea.

Comment: Have you verified what is getting passed in the fieldName variable?

Comment: yes it is the name of the field. Its the field on the web page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please post the HTML code? For the second question, I assume the no of drop downs is equal to or more than the no of items in the list.
You can iterate over the list to pick one item each from the list and select in the drop down.
Eg `for counter in range(0,Len(list_name)):
    item=list_name[counter]`